# Clean way to loop over a masked list in Julia

Tags: foreach, julia, reduction

In Julia, I have a list of neighbors of a location stored in `all_neighbors[loc]`. This allows me to quickly loop over these neighbors conveniently with the syntax `for neighbor in all_neighbors[loc]`. This leads to readable code such as the following:

```
active_neighbors = 0
for neighbor in all_neighbors[loc]
    if cube[neighbor] == ACTIVE
       active_neighbors += 1
    end
end
```

Astute readers will see that this is nothing more than a reduction. Because I'm just counting active neighbors, I figured I could do this in a one-liner using the `count` function. However,

```
# This does not work
active_neighbors = count(x->x==ACTIVE, cube[all_neighbors[loc]])
```

does not work because the `all_neighbors` mask doesn't get interpreted correctly as simply a mask over the `cube` array. Does anyone know the cleanest way to write this reduction? An alternative solution I came up with is:

```
active_neighbors = count(x->x==ACTIVE, [cube[all_neighbors[loc][k]] for k = 1:length(all_neighbors[loc])])
```

but I really don't like this because it's even less readable than what I started with. Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
count(x -> cube[x] == ACTIVE, all_neighbors[loc])
```

Comment: Extremely readable and exactly what I was looking for. Cheers.

Comment: or with comprehension: `count(cube[x] == ACTIVE for x in all_neighbors[loc])`

Comment: using a comprehension might be a bit slower (I am not sure if that matters in your use case).